# Ubuntu on not so old mobile phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have [LG GT500 Puccini](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_gt500_puccini-2898.php) and want to install any version of Ubuntu on it, but I don't have an idea how. You have ubuntu for mobile phone, but I don't know where to start. I search internet, but no success.

If there is some way to install Android or something else, I'll try it. Phone is not so old, serves me fine but I need many of new options like Viber, maps etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the install wiki of [Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) only the latest Nexus devices family are supported.

And a phone from 2009 is definitevly old in comparision to today smarthphones.

So if you want to **test** Ubuntu Touch you will need to get any of the Nexus devices listed in the install wiki.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install) is a list of supported devices by Ubuntu. Maybe there are some builds from users for other phones, too. 
But since your name phone isnt even running Android I think it is impossible to Install Ubuntu or Android on it. I don't think the hardware is able to run it. And even if you find a way to install Ubuntu or Android on it, it wont run very good.

So if you want to run Ubuntu, buy a Nexus 4 or a Galaxy Nexus.

By the way: This is a Forum for Ubuntu. So don't ask questions here, about installing Android on your phone.